# How to prevent System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get data from form collection as:

```
foreach (string key in col.Keys)// where col is object of form collection
{
    if (col["ConstituntName[" + i + "]"].ToString() != null)
    { 
        UserRecordSubClass usr = new UserRecordSubClass();
        usr.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(col["ConstituntName[" + i + "]"]);
        usr.ConstituentNameId = Convert.ToInt32(col["ConstituntNameId[" + i + "]"]);
    }

    i++
}
```

but when the `i` is 2, `ConstituntName["+i+"]` does not exist so it throws:

> System.NullReferenceException.

How can I prevent this exception in that case?

Comment: OT you are doing a `foreach (string key ..`, but are never using that `key` (in your posted code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check it for `null` before calling `.ToString()`:

```
if ( col["ConstituntName[" + i + "]"] != null 
     && col["ConstituntName[" + i + "]"].ToString() != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-),

```
if (col["ConstituntName[" + i + "]"]?.ToString() != null)
```

The null conditional operator gets evaluated to null if `col["ConstituntName[" + i + "]"]` or `col["ConstituntName[" + i + "]"].ToString()` gets evaluated to null